# Flutter: Issue with Asset Management in a Dependent Module Using FlutterGen

Tags: flutter, module, package

I'm facing an issue with asset management in my Flutter project, and I'm hoping someone can help me resolve it.

I have a main Flutter application (main_application) that imports another Flutter module (second_application). The second_application module uses FlutterGen for asset management.

The problem arises when I try to load the second_application module into my main_application. The main app is unable to find the images from the secondary application, and I'm receiving errors like:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/images/....gif".
Exception: Asset not found

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:369:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:811:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I've placed my assets directory within my source files, and I've also tried to include the assets from second_application in the main_application, but it never finds the path.

This is pubspec.yaml from second_application:

```
flutter_gen:
  integrations:
    flutter_svg: true

flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/.../
    - assets/images/.../
    - assets/images/.../
```

This creates a file called 'assets.gen.dart', and it's from this file that the images are loaded.

This is assets.gen.dart:

```
/// File path: assets/images/...gif
  AssetGenImage get myImage => const AssetGenImage(
      'assets/images/...gif');
```

It's from this file, which is present in the sources of second_application, that the error is triggered.

Could you help me ?